# How get register dbcontext in startup class for reference?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, singleton, startup, configure

I configure my DbContext with dependency injection in Startup, actually i need send my registered dbcontext to my class handler (**EventBusExtension.GetHandlers()**) but i dont know how get directly the context registered:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<cataDBContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServerConnect"))
            .Options;
        //*****************************************************************************

        services.AddSingleton(dbContextOptions);
        // Finally register the DbContextOptions:
        services.AddSingleton<cataDBContextOptions>();
        // This Factory is used to create the DbContext from the custom DbContextOptions:
        services.AddSingleton<IContextDBFactory, ContextDBFactory>();
        // Finally Add the Applications DbContext:
        services.AddDbContext<cataDBContext>();

        services.AddEventBusHandling(EventBusExtension.GetHandlers(Configuration));
   ...
}
```

How i can get and send the context to **EventBusExtension.GetHandlers()** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For how to get the instance in the Startup,you could use the following code:

```
//1.Register the service
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnnectionString")));

//2.Build an intermediate service provider
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

//3.Resolve the services from the service provider
var myDbContext = sp.GetService<MyDbContext>();  

//4.then you could pass the myDbContext to the EventBusExtension.GetHandlers()
```

Comment: But in this moment i use services.AddSingleton on my code, if use the steps 2 and 3 of your code, visual studio marks an advice "Calling BuildServiceProvider from application code results in aditional copy of singleton services being created..." then that is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted anser works but as mentioned in comments and [this microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ASP0000) ASP0000 calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created.
Calling BuildServiceProvider creates a second container, which can create torn singletons and cause references to object graphs across multiple containers.

A correct way to get LoginPath is to use the options pattern's built-in support for DI.
For example to use your dbContext to get all active Host URLs to apply in CORs instead of using services.AddCors(.... you can use this code :

```
services.AddOptions<CorsOptions>()
            .Configure<ApplicationDbContext>(
            (options, db) =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder =>
                 builder.WithOrigins(db.Set<MyHostsEntity>().Where(e => e.IsActive).Select(e => e.Url).ToArray())
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowCredentials()
                );
            }
            );
```